# Check whether a printer keeps a history of printed documents

Tags: printers

Are there resources to determine whether a consumer grade printer has some internal memory that stores the contents of printed documents, and/or information how to securely delete any such memory?

Answer (score 3):

Best resource would be to ask the manufacturer. How much printers cache and how they secure it varies widely.

For Consumer grade hardware, there is unlikely to be a mechanism for securely wiping the contents provided, since consumers don't need such a feature, so probably you'd need to look at physical destruction.

Comment: Depending on how user serviceable it is, you could remove the storage and wipe it externally.